# Error calculating LAG for time-series in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, time-series

I am trying to calculate LAG time from the last even, using something like the below.

```
SELECT *, LAG(time_in_status_seconds, 1) OVER (partition by user_email ORDER BY updated_at) AS time_in_status 
FROM "public"."Warm_Transfer_Status_Log" 
WHERE warm_transfer_status_id <> 'LOG_OUT' AND time_in_status_seconds IS NULL
```

In the outer query, I want to select records where `time_in_status_seconds` is `NULL` and compare that to records for the same user [`email`] where `time_in_status_seconds` is not  `NULL`.
It returns `NULL` for `time_in_status` rather than the `LAG`. Probably because all records where `time_in_status` is not null are already filtered out.

My results look like:

```
id      user_email          username            user_id status app     created_at              updated_at             time_in_status_seconds      time_in_status
13892   owltest@domain.com  OWLTest@domain.com  37491   FOLLOW_UP       CONNECT 2022-08-09 16:03:07.92  2022-08-09 16:03:07.92  NULL NULL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: add the table data and required result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using a nested query.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT *, LAG(time_in_status_seconds, 1) OVER (partition by user_email ORDER BY updated_at) AS time_in_status 
  FROM "public"."Warm_Transfer_Status_Log" 
  WHERE warm_transfer_status_id <> 'LOG_OUT'
) AS sub
WHERE sub.time_in_status_seconds IS NULL
```

I think that there must be a more efficient way of doing this.